# combine xml childs with same attribute in php

Tags: php, xml

I have surfed all over the web and tried different aproaches trying to achieve what I want, but all doesn't work. So I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

I have a xml file with multiple childs that has the same "name" attribute. From one child I need the attributes "created_for_playlist" and "sort_on_playlist" and from the other child with the same "name" attribute I need the "name" and the "duration". Both childs has different attributes...

Is it possible to get this information and merge the xml or write it direct in a array or even print or echo it directly?

This is my xml:

```
<assets>
    <asset name="Blanco fragment" unique_id="83609dd0-d22c-4217-afc6-64bccf742bee_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="1" created_for_layer="5" blank_shot="1" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Blanco fragment" unique_id="fd090636-fff1-4492-9e1d-2000ea96f1d7_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="7" created_for_layer="1" blank_shot="1" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Blanco fragment" unique_id="15298038-fce9-4a6d-9297-5ff3729ec0aa_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="1" created_for_layer="2" blank_shot="1" visible="1" sort_on_normal="0" />
    <asset name="Blanco fragment" unique_id="6bac7b34-83e0-46e5-8e9a-57542ee51914_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="1" created_for_layer="3" blank_shot="1" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Blanco fragment" unique_id="fb0c8b36-8d8e-4d28-83b8-0e1628de347a_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="1" created_for_layer="4" blank_shot="1" visible="1" />
    <asset name="programma" unique_id="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" type="playlist_shot" media-type="9" vam_state="14" created_for_layer="2" visible="1" sort_on_normal="1" />
    <asset name="Gat van Bolmers heet nu Kloosterplaats (Start project _Stadspark_).mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Gat van Bolmers heet nu Kloosterplaats (Start project _Stadspark_).mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="5725e2a4-8d1d-4f35-879f-81e8e8ca720c_Gat van Bolmers heet nu Kloosterplaats (Start project _Stadspark_).mp4" timescale="90000" duration="77410800" square_pixel_width="1920" square_pixel_height="1080" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Gat van Bolmers heet nu Kloosterplaats (Start project _Stadspark_).mp4" unique_id="7c8e3ce3-75b6-4691-9231-76e4ff20791b_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" veil_track_count="0" vam_state="8" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" alpha_track_count="1" audio_tracks="1" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" sort_on_playlist="0" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Straatmuzikanten, de gebroeders Maarten en Arthur.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Straatmuzikanten, de gebroeders Maarten en Arthur.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="b34202e0-9b57-405d-aed0-7f4bc72eb433_Straatmuzikanten, de gebroeders Maarten en Arthur.mp4" timescale="90000" duration="108514800" visible="1" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Straatmuzikanten, de gebroeders Maarten en Arthur.mp4" unique_id="bd3d0bbb-017b-4376-982e-d4fe54268b38_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" veil_track_count="0" sort_on_playlist="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" alpha_track_count="1" audio_tracks="1" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" vam_state="8" visible="1" />
    <asset name="vlaardingGlorie2Letzso.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\vlaardingGlorie2Letzso.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="dd5324c8-5cb2-48e6-b0ff-f3542bb47875_vlaardingGlorie2Letzso.mp4" timescale="24000" duration="50584000" visible="1" square_pixel_height="720" square_pixel_width="1280" />
    <asset media-type="4" type="vaSourcesManager" url="vaSourcesManager::URL" unique_id="Intensity Pro_1" name="Intensity Pro_1" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" square_pixel_width="720" visible="1" square_pixel_height="576" sourceGUID="F5568E19-5437-4088-8EAD-F1A9813CA4DD" />
    <asset name="live" unique_id="a1a3f2a4-09c9-4688-95ac-93d99290e32f_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_normal="2" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" alpha_track_count="1" veil_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" visible="1" vam_state="8" />
    <asset name="logo_live_popuptv.png" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\logo\logo_live_popuptv.png" type="file" media-type="1" unique_id="dbba37ef-5927-454b-86bc-c7e45f496276_logo_live_popuptv.png" timescale="40" duration="40" alpha_track_count="1" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="1" />
    <asset name="live1" unique_id="a0e775f3-9d64-4665-b7d1-191beb42ea0b_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" duration="180000000" vam_state="8" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="1" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" sort_on_playlist="3" visible="1" audio_tracks="1" />
    <asset name="logo_popuptv.png" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\logo\logo_popuptv.png" type="file" media-type="1" unique_id="618d1281-f130-4c16-a2cb-84ac43f796b5_logo_popuptv.png" timescale="40" duration="40" alpha_track_count="1" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="1" />
    <asset name="leader" unique_id="25e1bc1e-711e-4f1d-8ac9-246c9c9d5837_shot" type="playlist_shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" sort_on_normal="2" visible="1" created_for_layer="2" />
    <asset name="Leader.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\waterwegsport\Leader.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="8881007b-e636-481f-a15e-3579ff38ab2f_Leader.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="323000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Naamtitel_Fred.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\waterwegsport\Naamtitel_Fred.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="c6291487-799a-422d-9829-4d098a0fc551_Naamtitel_Fred.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="164000" square_pixel_height="1080" visible="1" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Naamtitel_Roy.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\waterwegsport\Naamtitel_Roy.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="a942381d-823c-4772-bc04-c13b22dd9de1_Naamtitel_Roy.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="164000" square_pixel_height="1080" visible="1" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Naamtitel_leon.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\waterwegsport\Naamtitel_leon.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="1742b789-203f-4ace-a05f-4a1fc07c318a_Naamtitel_leon.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="164000" visible="1" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Outro.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\waterwegsport\Outro.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="8b18b2ff-29bb-463d-8782-9e1a255094bc_Outro.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="449000" visible="1" square_pixel_width="1920" square_pixel_height="1080" />
    <asset name="outro" unique_id="e464133d-ea8f-489c-a963-676d1b6a1ca5_shot" type="playlist_shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" created_for_layer="2" visible="1" />
    <asset name="naamtitel_fred" unique_id="701be648-ab23-44c9-b16c-ac64869c98c9_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="0" created_for_layer="1" visible="1" still_image_tracks="0" video_tracks="1" alpha_track_count="0" audio_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" />
    <asset name="naamtitel_roy" unique_id="b34811b6-58d5-4747-8990-e0154c41356b_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="0" created_for_layer="1" visible="1" still_image_tracks="0" video_tracks="1" alpha_track_count="0" audio_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" />
    <asset name="naamtitel_leon" unique_id="9d5748b6-350f-4e28-a7ef-7962f8350037_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" created_for_layer="1" visible="1" still_image_tracks="0" video_tracks="1" alpha_track_count="0" audio_tracks="1" veil_track_count="0" />
    <asset name="Leader.mp4" unique_id="6258dfc5-c505-4ae3-96f7-5a2d387e5436_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" duration="12000000" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="1" audio_tracks="2" video_tracks="2" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="25e1bc1e-711e-4f1d-8ac9-246c9c9d5837_shot" sort_on_playlist="1" visible="1" still_image_tracks="0" />
    <asset name="Outro.mp4" unique_id="441c9715-82c4-449a-8af7-1366575ccbac_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" duration="17000000" video_tracks="2" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" audio_tracks="2" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="e464133d-ea8f-489c-a963-676d1b6a1ca5_shot" sort_on_playlist="2" visible="1" alpha_track_count="1" />
    <asset name="18 april was er weer de Culinaire Markt Schiedam 2015.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\18 april was er weer de Culinaire Markt Schiedam 2015.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="a9f676a7-3051-41f2-bee8-8cb4c9285aa8_18 april was er weer de Culinaire Markt Schiedam 2015.mp4" timescale="90000" duration="70041600" square_pixel_height="1080" visible="1" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="18 april was er weer de Culinaire Markt Schiedam 2015.mp4" unique_id="9d27c059-571e-41bd-bf27-957726ed862a_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" sort_on_playlist="4" still_image_tracks="0" alpha_track_count="1" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" veil_track_count="0" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Komkids Kennisdag Schiedam 2015.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Komkids Kennisdag Schiedam 2015.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="021f4fd9-5414-4979-b390-ddc637b16905_Komkids Kennisdag Schiedam 2015.mp4" timescale="90000" duration="37407600" square_pixel_height="1080" visible="1" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Komkids Kennisdag Schiedam 2015.mp4" unique_id="a7e2ad99-f214-46af-9a50-c428b57357bf_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_playlist="7" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" vam_state="8" veil_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" alpha_track_count="1" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Opening Servicepunt Woningverbetering nu op de Singel 85 in Schiedam.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Opening Servicepunt Woningverbetering nu op de Singel 85 in Schiedam.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="eba37bd7-47d0-4246-8a21-17ab52722b68_Opening Servicepunt Woningverbetering nu op de Singel 85 in Schiedam.mp4" timescale="90000" duration="44744400" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="0" />
    <asset name="Opening Servicepunt Woningverbetering nu op de Singel 85 in Schiedam.mp4" unique_id="f56b1b55-bb26-4e4c-9220-0021809bab9a_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_playlist="8" vam_state="8" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" visible="1" alpha_track_count="1" />
    <asset name="Vld glorie live owe lullen band.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Vld glorie live owe lullen band.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="97c72bcd-042a-4b8f-850f-f62d918b58f0_Vld glorie live owe lullen band.mp4" timescale="24000" duration="45174000" square_pixel_height="720" square_pixel_width="1280" visible="0" />
    <asset name="Vld glorie live owe lullen band.mp4" unique_id="b512f5c5-937f-4964-af79-c9f522c65908_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="14" alpha_track_count="0" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" visible="1" sort_on_playlist="9" />
    <asset name="13-04-2015_Popuptv_opening culture candy2.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\13-04-2015_Popuptv_opening culture candy2.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="492d21bf-3290-47ac-ae1c-d90c1003462a_13-04-2015_Popuptv_opening culture candy2.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="7326000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="0" />
    <asset name="13-04-2015_Popuptv_opening culture candy2.mp4" unique_id="1fe4622d-57d1-49db-a998-e1671b3553f5_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" visible="1" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" alpha_track_count="0" sort_on_playlist="11" />
    <asset name="De Maatschappij Vlaardingen V2_01-04-2015.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\De Maatschappij Vlaardingen V2_01-04-2015.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="ba77ead9-3a02-4fa5-85d2-e1c11ed9013d_De Maatschappij Vlaardingen V2_01-04-2015.mp4" timescale="50000" duration="10650000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="0" />
    <asset name="De Maatschappij Vlaardingen V2_01-04-2015.mp4" unique_id="5a9b9eff-89d2-4c53-adb6-a9d5f8e4d917_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_playlist="14" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" vam_state="8" visible="1" />
    <asset name="popuptv_peuterfestival2.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\popuptv_peuterfestival2.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="159ea9af-d7d6-4b1a-a551-0ac295bfe274_popuptv_peuterfestival2.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="4460000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" visible="0" />
    <asset name="popuptv_peuterfestival2.mp4" unique_id="a81a8278-6a7b-4a41-ab50-72e2ceadb9d6_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" sort_on_playlist="12" visible="1" />
    <asset name="live4" unique_id="bdaf045e-5470-4997-adb7-4dac78f42d88_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" visible="1" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" alpha_track_count="1" sort_on_playlist="13" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" vam_state="8" audio_tracks="1" duration="180000000" veil_track_count="0" />
    <asset name="live2" unique_id="766cd8dd-e0ba-4197-b203-1553f2b0eba7_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" vam_state="8" duration="180000000" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" alpha_track_count="1" visible="1" sort_on_playlist="6" />
    <asset name="Live3" unique_id="2aadf2e7-2045-4d96-8192-b054c4c5e7b8_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" audio_tracks="1" duration="180000000" visible="1" sort_on_playlist="10" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" alpha_track_count="1" veil_track_count="0" vam_state="8" />
    <asset name="Live5" unique_id="cd3d1da8-97f3-4720-b403-d05eb60ff641_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" duration="156000000" vam_state="8" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" visible="1" sort_on_playlist="16" alpha_track_count="1" />
    <asset name="Uw videopitch .mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Uw videopitch .mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="dd6434de-d781-434b-8478-8944ff0dd2c8_Uw videopitch .mp4" timescale="25000" duration="252000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Uw videopitch .mp4" unique_id="c5410859-4831-4dfe-83dd-b7692af12ddb_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_playlist="5" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" vam_state="8" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Like ons en volg ons.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Like ons en volg ons.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="36e45769-499b-41c0-b317-907e71d59017_Like ons en volg ons.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="197000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Like ons en volg ons.mp4" unique_id="eab7726e-7cae-4b7e-a69b-72e6ce347e6e_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_playlist="15" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" vam_state="8" visible="1" />
    <asset name="Nieuwsoverzicht Commercial.mp4" url="D:\wirecast\popuptv\video\201504\Nieuwsoverzicht Commercial.mp4" type="file" video_tracks="1" audio_tracks="1" media-type="1" unique_id="15e92e4c-1e52-4fe4-963f-be779ac7ce2e_Nieuwsoverzicht Commercial.mp4" timescale="25000" duration="239000" square_pixel_height="1080" square_pixel_width="1920" />
    <asset name="Nieuwsoverzicht Commercial.mp4" unique_id="7eda8cc2-d51f-48e2-aa83-319c4a802912_shot" type="shot" media-type="9" sort_on_playlist="2" audio_tracks="1" video_tracks="1" still_image_tracks="0" veil_track_count="0" alpha_track_count="0" created_for_layer="2" shot_in_playlist="1" created_for_playlist="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot" vam_state="8" visible="1" />
</assets>
```

This is what I have so far in php. all the files are placed it the right order (based on attribute "sort_on_playlist") and it shows the name of the file (without .mp4) and it shows only the data of the playlist "programma" based on the attribute "created_for_playlist"...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('teststream_001.wcst');
$alleAssets_naam=array();

$nodeNaam = $xml->assets->asset->attributes()->name;

foreach ($xml->assets->asset as $node) {
    if ($node->attributes()->created_for_playlist=="8228566d-0204-49ea-9089-7a8de978447c_shot") {
        $indexnummer =intval($node->attributes()->sort_on_playlist);
        $naam=strval($node->attributes()->name);
        $charnaam = strlen($naam);
        if($charnaam > 7){
            $naamkort = substr($naam, 0, -4);
        }else{
            $naamkort = $naam;
        }

        $a[$indexnummer] = $naamkort;
        echo "<br/>nummer ",$indexnummer," is: ",$a[$indexnummer];
    }   

}




$max=count($alleAssets_naam);
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    echo "<br/>",$i," : ",$alleAssets_naam[$i];
}
```

I hope I made myself clear and someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to reach as well?

Comment: it helps when you first understand why the XML has duplicate names and which of the many duplicate looking entries you're actually looking for by the specification of this format. That is like finding the correct criteria to query the data from the document. That starts with getting a better understanding of the XML strucutre you have there. Apart from that, XPath is often a good way to query XML documents, but it's a language of it's own. In any case it helps you develop your own understanding first before looking on how to implement the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will combine rows with matching names into one. At the end you will have a new XML where every row contains what you wanted. You can now iterate over rows and do more stuff with them.

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(/* Your XML goes here */);

$xPath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xPath->query('//asset[@name][@created_for_playlist]');

$newDoc = new \DOMDocument();
$newDoc->formatOutput = true;
$assetsElement = $newDoc->createElement('assets');
$newDoc->appendChild($assetsElement);

foreach($elements as $key => $element){
    $name = $element->getAttribute('name');
    $newAsset = $newDoc->importNode($element);

    $searchResult = $xPath->query("//asset[@name='$name'][@duration]");
    if(1== $searchResult->length){
        foreach($searchResult->item(0)->attributes as $attribute){
            $newAsset->setAttribute($attribute->name, $attribute->value);
        }
        $assetsElement->appendChild($newAsset);
    }
}

echo $newDoc->saveXML();
```

Comment: woowww this code is great! Thank you so much!  @awons   I only have one problem with the new xml.. each node is placed in the node above... so the first asset is placed in the parent assets.. but the next asset is placed in the first asset, the third asset is placed in the second.. and so on..